# Using substitution to reduce equation from one form to another

Tags: polynomials

Let $f(x,y)$ be a second degree irreducible polynomial. Now,I want to find linear polynomials $X=\phi_1(x,y)$ and $Y=\phi_2(x,y)$ so that $f(x,y)$ can be rewriten as $Y-X^2$ or $XY-1$. Is there any systematic way of finding $\phi_1(x,y)$ and $\phi_2(x,y)$?

And is there any systematic way to solve these kind of problems?

Comment: I suppose you want $X$ nonconstant in $Y-X^2$ and $X,Y$ both nonconstant in $XY-1$ ? Otherwise, the problem is trivial.

Comment: Yes,$X$ and $Y$ should be nonconstants

Comment: For $XY-1$, you are simply asking about how to factorize $f(x,y)+1$. There are plenty of factorization algorithms, start with wikipedia.

Comment: For $Y-X^2$, the question looks rather silly : for any $X$ you simply let $Y=X^2+f$

Comment: How is Y linear then? I want X and Y to be linear polynomials.

Comment: “How is $Y$ linear?” Well, $Y=X^2+f$ will be linear iff the terms in $x^2,xy$ and $y^2$ cancel out.